# How to Post An Image+ Text on friend's wall

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ios4, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post an image and a text to a friend's wall. I am not supposed to use the dialog box, I am using stream.publish to post directly. 
I can successfully post it to my own wall ( The logged in  user), but I need to find a way to post on friend's wall.

Here is my code I need someone to help me add to  few lines of code to post to friend's wall.

```
/*
Friends URL To whom's wall I need to post. 
 **I need to figure out how to use friendURL in my code. 
So that post goes to my    friend's wall.
Below code is posting to my own  wall.**

*/ 
NSString *friendURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                              @"http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=%@",
                              marriedFriend.userID];
SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

NSDictionary* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary 
                                                       dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"Always Running",@"text",@"http://itsti.me/",
                                                       @"href", nil], nil];

NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];
NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary 
dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"a long run by Rahul...", @"name",
                            @"The Facebook Running app", @"caption",
                            @"it is fun", @"description",
                            @"http://itsti.me/", @"href", nil];
NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary
                               dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Share on Facebook",  @"user_message_prompt",
                               actionLinksStr, @"action_links",
                               attachmentStr, @"attachment",
                               nil];



[facebookRef  requestWithMethodName:@"stream.publish" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using the old API.  Using the newer Graph API you can do:

```
// replace PROFILE_ID with your friend's ID
[facebookRef requestWithGraphPath:@"PROFILE_ID/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

[See more documentation here.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts)

Comment: Now I am facing another problem. Can you tell how can I post feed to multiple friends. As I am using single instance of the facebookref variable.?

Comment: Make multiple requests.  I did not see any way to post to multiple feeds in the documentation.